# counting impressions under high load

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

Editing my question:

I want to count impressions (hits) on my website, and i'm using PHP 5.3 and Yii framework.
I'm trying to run an application under Yii framework.

My app is getting ~600K users per day.

As suggested before the server may be crashing due to multiple connection trying to update the impressions.

My question is: what is the recommended method for counting impression (hits, visits) to my site?

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing (and I assume you meant you increased) the max connections in MySQL won't help if you're running into hardware limits.  The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) addresses this.

I'd suggest examining your code and seeing what kind of refactoring you can do to reduce DB calls, and if that doesn't work, then considering upgrading the hardware.  It would probably make sense to try and profile your stuff as well to determine which functions are causing all the load/connections.

Comment: thanks for the answer - i'm pretty sure i'm not running to H/W limitation (i checked the server status) and i know which function is causing me the headache (it's the one counting impressions on my site..but i need to count each impression so i cant lose it)

Comment: While the overall load on the server may not appear to high, you may be running into cases where the instantaneous load is - e.g. you have 1,000+ clients simultaneously attempting to count the impressions, which could cause the error . . .

Comment: If that's it, you're hitting a hardware limitation of what your server can handle . . . you'll need to refactor your code and find a better way to count impressions, or upgrade the hardware . . .

Comment: Did you try to use persistent mysql connections?

Comment: @N.B as i understood every place i read discourage such a behavior, can you please explain why i need to use persistence? and how would it help?

Comment: @Danny - they aren't ideal, however you are running into problem of not having enough connections for your users and you're just updating a table - quick fix is to allow persistent connections for that purpose. It's not great, but the other solutions are slightly more complex.